# Forcing download of PDF on iPad

Tags: javascript, ios, apache, ipad, cordova

Previous questions about this on SO haven't been much help.

I'm trying to force a PDF to download on the iPad. However, the default behaviour of both Safari and the Phonegap/Cordova InAppBrowser on the iPad is to display the PDF, not download it. I already manipulate the MIME-type in Apache, and this makes the download work properly in all desktop browsers.

I've tried both:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "\.pdf$" requested_pdf=pdf
Header add Content-Disposition "attachment" env=requested_pdf
```

and:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(pdf)$">
  ForceType application/octet-stream
  Header set "Content-disposition" "attachment; filename=test.pdf"
</FilesMatch>
```

Both Safari and InAppBrowser still display the PDF, instead of downloading. Yet I've seen there are sites able to force a PDF to download, possibly through client-side JavaScript.

Any ideas?

Comment: After a couple quick searches, it looks like the _iPad_ does not support the behaviour you're looking for unless you create your own app to fetch the file in the first place, and even then it may end up sandboxed

Comment: Sadly, it looks like you're right. None of the sites claiming to allow a PDF download I've looked at, appear to work. At best they simply display a PDF, at worst they have a "Download" button that does nothing.